# Change rows based on condition

Tags: sql, if-statement, where-clause

I got a table with a country column and each country has multiple rows.

I want to query rows where seq_no is equal to 1. However, if the country is USA or Canada, I want the seq_no to be equal to 2, something like this:

```
SELECT language
FROM table
WHERE IF(country = 'USA' OR 'Canada')
      THEN (seq_no = '2')
      ELSE (seq_no = '1')
    ENDIF;
```

Is that possible?

Comment: You want to update the `seq_no` column in the table or you want to adapt the condition for `seq_no` based on the value of `country`?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results as tabular text. It is not clear at all what you mean by "change rows" whatsoever.

Comment: Please provide an output example in a table form

Comment: I update the question so it will be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to apply different condition on column based on another column, you can use `case` in you `where` clause. For example:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE seq_no = CASE WHEN country in ('USA', 'Canada')
      THEN '2'
      ELSE '1' END;
```

Input:

| country | seq_no |
| --- | --- |
| USA | 2 |
| Canada | 1 |
| Other | 1 |

Output:

| country | seq_no |
| --- | --- |
| USA | 2 |
| Other | 1 |

Demo can be seen [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zr5N1iMc).

Comment: What would happened if I got multiple rows in the table with USA and Canada that have seq_no 1 & 2?

Comment: @Tal1992, Only those which have 2 will be selected.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: line 4:4 Wrong arguments ''1'': Unsafe compares between different types are disabled for safety reasons. If you know what you are doing, please set hive.strict.checks.type.safety to false and make sure that hive.mapred.mode is not set to 'strict' to proceed. Note that you may get errors or incorrect results if you make a mistake while using some of the unsafe features.`

Comment: @Tal1992, if your `seq_no` is of number type change `'1'` to `1` and `'2'` tp `2`.

Answer (score 1):

You would translate your IF conditions into the conditions themselves, like this:

```
SELECT 
  language 
FROM 
  table 
WHERE 
  (
    (
      country = 'USA' 
      OR country = 'Canada'
    ) 
    AND seq_no = 2
  ) 
  OR seq_no = 1
```

It may be more readable if you use IN() for the 2 countries

```
SELECT 
  language 
FROM 
  table 
WHERE 
  ( country IN('USA','Canada') AND seq_no = 2) 
  OR seq_no = 1
```